# calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener android studio

Tags: android, datetime

everytime user select date the TextView only showing current date

```
public void initOverall(){
    TextView dateTest = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cnvrt);
    CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String selectedDates = sdf.format(new Date(calendarView.getDate()));
            dateTest.setText(selectedDates);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the date from within the callback to the `CallendarView`?

Comment: how? sory total noob here

Comment: Why you don't use the parameters of the callback ?

Comment: According to [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView) you can set the date by calling `setDate` and passing the date to the view. You need to declare your `callendrView` => `final CallendarView callendarView` and inside the callback set `callendarView.setDate(calendarView.getDate())`. This may look absurd and even may cause OOM exeption because it may loop, but worth a try.

Comment: still same tho, even the background selected date stick to current date

Comment: im really confused, my program work perfectly on old kitkat samsung tab, but wont work on newer OS

Comment: what SDK are you using?

Comment: it work on sdk 19, but not working in sdk 25 and newer

Comment: the compiler im using sdk 28

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you just selected a date but not got it as *onSelectedDayChange* stage.

And the date you chosen was saved in parameters of *onSelectedDayChange*.

You can try the following code :

```
public void initOverall(){
        final TextView dateTest = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cnvrt);
        final CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                String selectedDates = sdf.format(new Date(year-1900,month,dayOfMonth));
                dateTest.setText(selectedDates);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: wow thanks its works,kind sir dare you explain to me what the function of "year-1900"?

Comment: Press your ctrl and click Date, you will see some information in source code of Android Studio. I guess CalendarView doesn't need to show the date before 1900.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Apart from using the old-fashioned classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` you are also using the deprecated three-arg `Date` constructor. Never do that. It was deprecated because it works unreliably across time zones.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

```
public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, Month.values()[month], dayOfMonth);
    String selectedDates = date.toString();
    dateTest.setText(selectedDates);
}
```

As has been said in comments, you need to pick up the date that the user has chosen from the arguments passed to `onSelectedDayChange`. Unfortunately the `month` passed is 0-based, a number in the interval from 0 for January through 11 for December. `Month.values()[month]` is my trick for obtaining the correct `Month` object. If you prefer, you may instead just add 1:

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month + 1, dayOfMonth);
```

I am further exploiting the fact that `LocalDate.toString` produces the format you want, so we need no explicit formatter. The format is ISO 8601.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score -1):

```
CalendarView v = new CalendarView( this );
 v.setOnDateChangeListener( new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
       this.calendar = new GregorianCalendar( year, month, dayOfMonth );
    }//met
 });
```